# bash, while loop, source file return error in 1 case; how to catch to variable?

Tags: bash

I have this part of code.

```
while IFS=' ' read -ra var
do

    source SCRIPT 2>&1 | tee -a $log

done <<< $main_config
```

SCRIPT

```
ssh -i id_rsa "${var[5]}"@"${var[1]}" -n 'sudo su - postgres -c "pg_dump -Fc '${var[10]}' > /tmp/'${var[12]}'"'
```

This part go through for 10 lines (from `$main_config` variable) and in 1 case, there is error message, DB does not exist.

```
pg_dump: chyba spojení s databází "eetB" selhalo: FATAL:  database "eetB" does not exist
```

How can I get info/error code if loop finished with 1 error message? For example store to some variable. And is it possible in this case when error message is from another server?

I tried `if`, `return`, but without success.

Simply, how can I get error code in case of finish `source` with some errors?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

There was problem in SCRIPT. `ssh` command was succesfull, so it returns `0`. I have to change SCRIPT, dumping directly on localhost.

```
ssh -i id_rsa "${var[5]}"@"${var[1]}" -n 'sudo su - postgres -c "pg_dump -Fc '${var[10]}'"' > ${var[11]}/${var[12]}
```

But now, I have problem. If I have `tee` command, it returns me `true` in case of `false`. Without `tee` it is OK.

```
while IFS=' ' read -ra var
do
    if
        source scripts/$script_name 2>&1 | tee -a $log
    then
        status="true"
    else
        status="false"
    fi
done <<< $main_config
```

Could you tell me where is the catch?

Comment: Since you are using bash, you should be able to access the exit status of each element of the pipeline separately from the `PIPESTATUS` array

Comment: @steeldriver No luck, it depends just on output contain some output, anything, it shows me FALSE in all cases. I don't understand. I need just store `rc=1` in case that output for one of loop shows me error.

Comment: @steeldriver Seems there is an same issue, with DB dump via ssh, it returns 0 in this case, but if I will change command for example to `cat ${var[13]}` and this array variable is missing on one of line in `$main_config`, it works. Probably return code is `0` in case even loop don't store anything because database not exist. Is it possible?

Comment: @steeldriver Now I understand, return code 0 is just in case if all is ok, return code 1 is for some error in case of db connection (?), return code 2 is for missing file, etc. Now it is working, but still return me `0` is I add `tee -a $log`. Why?

Comment: When you do a pipeline like `somecommand | othercommand`, you will get the exit status of `othercommand`. In your case, you are therefore testing the exit status of `tee`. In bash, you can use `PIPESTATUS` to obtain the exit status of the other side of the pipe. So something like `somecommand | tee -a "$log"; if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" -eq 0 ]; then echo "somecommand succeeded"; else echo "somecommand failed"; fi`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, it works! Never heard about `PIPESTATUS`.

Comment: you got the quoting wrong try this `var=({a..z});a=(ssh -i ...); for b in "${a[@]}"; do echo $((++c)): "$b"; done` (fill out the rest of the ssh line) read quote pairs from left to right literally.